# Can't convert date value get from SQL database

Tags: c#, date

I had set the date datatype to date in sql server but when i want get value from it will output datetime value "9/22/2016 12:00:00 AM".

```
DataGridViewRow row = cell.OwningRow;
string DATE = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to format it on the front end:

```
((DateTime)row.Cells[2].Value).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Comment: This tried before come out error "No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments"

Answer (score 2):

Ok, you are usting `ToString()` method and it returns `string` value. You can retrieve `DateTime` with [explicit casting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx):

```
DataGridViewRow row = cell.OwningRow;
DateTime DATE = (DateTime) row.Cells[2].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the date to the desired format

```
DateTime DATE = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
```

When you want to display the DATE, use the format "yyyy-MM-dd" (as per your screen shot).

Answer (score 0):

Convert string into datetime and you can give the format like this way ...
it will works....

```
 DateTime d=Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
 textBox1.Text = d.ToShortDateString();
```